# Is it possible to query the github api for any repos that a user is a collaborator on?

Tags: node.js, github, github-api

I seem to be missing if it's possible to query github for any / all repos that a member is a collaborator on?  I'm writing a github oauth node app, and I'm trying to get, not only the members repos, but any repos they are a collaborator on.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this endpoint should help you with that:

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-your-repositories

Notice the description and the available parameters.

Comment: Boom!  I had missed the affiliation param, thanks Ivan!